# Запятая перед тире

Tags: запятая

Читаю у А.Платонова:

> Она спала в коробке, - там лежала
> вата, там воробью будет мягко.

Мне не понятно, почему рядом стоят запятая и тире. Если разбирать это предложение как сложное бессоюзное, то должен быть один знак и, наверное, лучше тире, а вот для чего автор поставил запятую? Может, это авторский знак, но он тоже что-то должен обозначать.

Answer (score 2):

См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник.

> **§ 130…** **Примечание 1.** В бессоюзном сложном предложении может
> ставиться запятая и тире как единый
> знак, особенно при значении
> присоединения во второй части
> предложения (**знак этот в настоящее
> время утрачивает свою активность**):
>
> *Смотреть наружу не было смысла, —
> тьма ночи налетала всё более густыми
> волнами* (Пауст.);
>
> *Даже вода взволновалась, — вот до
> чего взыгрались лягушки* (Пришв.);
>
> *В саду, в горах сверкали белые и
> небольшие лампочки, — было похоже на
> иллюминацию* (Пауст.);
>
> *Широкий подъезд показался мне
> совершенно пуст, — это показалось мне
> странным* (Кав.).

Comment: Примечание 2. Запятую и тире как единый знак препинания не следует смешивать с сочетанием этих знаков, когда тире разграничивает части бессоюзного сложного предложения, а запятая отделяет впереди стоящую обособленную конструкцию или придаточную часть предложения:

Comment: Ну и?... Какое отношение примечание 2 имеет к разбираемому нами предложению?

Comment: Слава, запятая закрывает первую часть БСП,а тире указывает, что дальше идет причина, обоснование.

Comment: Серж, прочтите повнимательнее примечание 2, которое Вы пытаетесь притянуть к нашему случаю. В этом примечании говорится, что ЗАПЯТАЯ ОТДЕЛЯЕТ ВПЕРЕДИ СТОЯЩУЮ ОБОСОБЛЕННУЮ КОНСТРУКЦИЮ ИЛИ ПРИДАТОЧНУЮ ЧАСТЬ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ! У нас ни того, ни другого нет! Есть ЕДИНЫЙ ЗНАК "запятая + тире", разграничивающий части БСП (см. примечание 1).

Answer (score 0):

Запятая закрывает первую часть БСП, а тире  - так как вторая часть бессоюзной структуры имеет значение причины, обоснования.

Comment: А как же правило? Когда второе предложение указывает причину того, о чем говорится в первом, ставится двоеточие. И при тире в бессоюзном СП запятая не ставится, или здесь какое-то исключение? Просто по правилам в БСП ставится или запятая, или тире, или двоеточие.

Comment: Во второй части бессоюзной структуры  возможно употребление и двоеточия, и тире. Тире в таких случаях считается менее книжным знаком, характерным для художественной и публицистической литературы. **См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 260-262.**

Comment: Пройдитесь по ссылке, которую привел Слава, там это правило есть.